# Beautiful Soup order-based search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a series of very flat webpages, where the structure that matters to me is that I want to find all elements that occur after a `h2` element with a known id. The elements I want to find after this `h2` element are `p`, `blockquote`, and `center`. Ordering is important and needs to be preserved in locating these elements. I should also say that all the elements of interest are siblings in the sense of being at the same organizational level, right next to on another. How can I do this?

Here's what I tried:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
# here is the title
h =  soup.find("h2", {"id":"content"})
print(h.text) # correct, so we're in the right place
print(h.next_sibling)
```

But the final print statement just prints a `None`. I also tried this:

```
i = h.next
print(i.text)
```

But this raises a NavigableString error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(i.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr)
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The elements I'm looking for are definitely at the same level as this `h2` element and occur afterwords in the HTML. How can I find them in the BS navigation schema?

Comment: Can you give an example of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `h.next_sibling`, BeautifulSoup returns whatever element comes next at the same level. Now, this element can either be a tag or a standalone string. My guess is that there is some standalone string in your HTML document that precedes the HTML tags you are looking for.

Example:

```
html = '<h1>A header</h1>Some random text<p>A paragraph</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
h = soup.find('h1') # Contains <h1>A header</h1>
print(h.next_sibling) # Prints u'Some random text', not the p tag
```

Comment: I see. In that case how would I get past that standalone string?

Comment: Using my example, try `h.find_next('p')` to get the tag you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps I have an old BS version. I had to use findNext() and find_next generated a very strange error message about NoneType...

Comment: Yup, sounds like an older version.